# Refactor controller in laravel to work in another controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to remove angular from a page on our laravel website, because we're removing angular altogether. Currently, we have a controller in laravel doing what we need, but someone in the past used an angular module and html template to display it.

Currently, I need to take what this controller is doing:

**BuildOrderFormController.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'dealer' => 'required|numeric',
        'form' => 'required',
    ]);

    // check to make sure this dealer can order from this formid
    $dealer = Input::get('dealer');
    $form = Input::get('form');

    $aa = FormBuilder::getcompanyfromform($form) + 0;

    $comp = CustomerDataNew::getcomp($dealer);

    if (!in_array($aa, $comp)) {
        return "Error: Dealer can't use this form";
    }

    try {
        return json_encode(FormBuilder::BuildOrderForm($dealer, $aa, $form));
    } catch (OPSException $e) {
        return json_encode(['error' => $e->getUserMessage()]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
```

and apply it to this controller:

**OrderController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $forms = FormBuilder::Orderforms($this->dealer);
    return view('Shop.Order.index')->with('forms', $forms);
}

public function show($id)
{
    $cart_num = Access::getAttrValue('cart_num');
    if (!$cart_num) {
        $cart = 0;
    } else {
        $find_cart = Cart::find($cart_num);
        if ($find_cart  && $find_cart->orderform == $id) {
            $cart = $cart_num;
        } else {
            $cart = 0;
        }
    }
    return view('Shop.Order.show')
        ->with('dealer', $this->dealer)
        ->with('cart', $cart)
        ->with('form', $id);

}
```

The `store` function builds the json object with the order form data we need, I just need to use it in the new controller because that's the controller laravel is using.

I've already copied the html template to the appropriate blade in laravel, but once this is figured out, I need to wrap the html with a foreach loop in the blade, but until I get this fixed I don't know what variables to use in the foreach loop.

Can anyone explain how I would refactor the `buildorderformcontroller.php` code to work in the other controller?

Comment: What about simple moving the `store()` method from the `BuildOrderFormController.php` file into `OrderController.php`?

Comment: I have tried that to a degree, but the first problem is that the page is using the ```show``` function , not ```store```. But order controller is showing the corect blade as the returned view, buildorderformcontroller just happens to be the current one building the data in JSON correctly. I need to take what it's doing there, specifically, and integrate that into the ```show``` function

Comment: Move it to the `BuildOrderFormController.php` and call it from inside the `show()` method like `$this->store(request())`.

Comment: Ok I've tried that but in order for it to show on the front end (in the blade) I need to put a foreach loop around my html code, so in this case would my foreach by $form as $forms?